# Play Framework 2.4.0 - How to add an external java project dependency to play-java application project

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, sbt, dependency-management

I've created a play-java web application with the command:
**activator new "c:\workspace\PlayServer"**

I'm working in **Eclipse** and created in the same workspace another java project (regular java project) named "Common".

Now, i have the following project structure:

```
c:\workspace
   \--- Common (Java project)
      \--- src
           \--- comm
              \--- messages
   \--- PlayServer (Play-java 2.4.0 web application project)
      \--- app/controllers
      \--- app/views
      \--- conf
      \--- project
```

I would like to access the classes of "Common" project at "PlayServer".
In Eclipse - i've added the "Common" project dependency to the Java build path of the play application project, and all the projects were build successfully and i can access all the classes of "Common" at the "PlayServer" play application project.

However, when I run or Debug the "PlayServer" with activator run command,
i'm receving errors:
**[error] c:\workspace\PlayServer\app\controllers\Application.java;6 
error: package comm.messages.WebMessage does not exist 

[error] import comm.messages.WebMessage**

Which means the playframework can't find the classes of "Common" java eclipse project.
After searching a lot about this problem i've found in general, that there are 3 solutions to this: 

**1.** Publish to my external java project to Ivy and resolve in the play project's build.sbt file as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Adding it here somehow..
)
```

But i didn't find any simple tutorial which can guide me how to publish my external java project and resolve it in play project's build.sbt file.
The build sbt file is a bit mystery to me.

**2.** Directly reference my external project, in the play project's build.sbt.
I tried to do the following at my **build.sbt** - **which also didn't really work:**

**// Option 1:**

```
lazy val core = ProjectRef(file("../Common"), "Common")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(common )
```

**// Option 2:**

```
lazy val common = RootProject(file("../common"))
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(common )
```

**// Option 3:**

```
lazy val common = file("../common").getAbsoluteFile.toURI
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(common )
```

I've read at the SBT documentation that i should add to the "Common" project a **"build.sbt"** file, but i don't know what to declare in it.
In case the "Common" project must be also a SBT project, i know all the java sources should be in: **"/src/main/java"** but i saw at the SBT documentation that it is configurable. So, the **main issue** is that i still don't manage to make my external java project be compiled and recognized by my play web application. 
For now i just created an empty **build.sbt** file at the **"Common"** project directory.

**3.** Create a **lib/** directory in the root of my play project and then add jar files to that directory. This solution will require that each of my external java projects like "Common" will need to create "jar" file automatically in every build, and also to copy the generated jars to my **"PlayServer"** **lib directory**. Also, i've read that the "lib" solution is for **unmanaged dependecies**, therefore i'm not sure this solution is effective and correct, due to the fact that play framework uses **SBT with ivy.**

**My question is:**
Which one of the methods is the most preffered and recommended to use? 
and how can i implement it? 
I didn't success to find any best practices about this issue or any basic tutorials that can demonstrate how to do any of the above solutions.

Comment: Anyone? will appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this approach to work well following the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects) which explains the structure Play uses for packaging separate projects.

Two repositories with Git, one for `common` and one for `PlayServer`.  Checkout `Common` to its own workspace but also checkout it into `PlayServer`'s workspace within a folder named `modules`:

```
c:\workspace
   \--- Common (checked out from Git)
      \--- src
           \--- comm
              \--- messages
   \--- PlayServer (Play-java 2.4.0 web application project)
      \--- app/controllers
      \--- app/views
      \--- conf
      \--- project
      \--- modules
         \--- Common (checked out from Git)
            \--- src
                 \--- comm
                    \--- messages
```

(Note how `Common` is checked out twice, to its own workspace, and also within `PlayServer/modules`.)

In the `.gitignore` for the `PlayServer` app, you can tell it to ignore `modules\Common` as it's got its own separate Git repository.

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects) explains on how to get the `modules/Common` and `PlayServer` to work together as separate projects, and there's a [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/josh-padnick/play-multiproject-template) showing how Play's subproject works.  Note that this sample uses Play 2.3 however 2.4's [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) doesn't mention any changes and therefore the same steps can be taken.

### Update (see comments)

`Build.sbt` would be something like:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(common)
  .dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = project.in(file("../common"))
```

Everything else is as per the sample I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  your solution is not really suitable for our purpose, since we work in a private local network and using TFS for source control. Also, your approach demands to duplicate every external project, which sounds very complex to use and maintain, we really prefer not to duplicate all our external java projects (we have 15 external projects as "Common"). Btw, in your solution did you created a "build.sbt" file at all the duplicates of the "Common" project -if so, can you please upload & explain about their content vs your play project's "build.sbt" content which will add them?

Comment: See updated answer. Everything's the same as the sample on GitHub/documentation, with some differences as I explained in the updated answer.

Comment: Tnx! i'll try it tomorrow and update. Do you know why you have to duplicate your library projects and reference them only as sub-projects instead of external project outside of the play project's scope? Also, i've noticed that all of your library projects don't contain java source files in custom layouts like "common/src/comm/messages/*.java" but only in the default layout paths of play project like: "/modules/customer/app/models/customer/MyLibrary.java" or "/modules/customer/app/controllers/customer/Application.java", if the java files will be in different custom folders, will it still work?